# MPI checkpoint usage

Tags: mpi, checkpoint

I'd like to take advantage of MPI checkpoint feature to save my job. According to the suggestion at https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Checkpointing

I should be able to send SIGUSR1 to mpiexec ( in my case, I send it to mpirun ) to trigger a checkpoint. However, when I do so I don't see any file saved in my checkpoint directory that I specified with -ckpoint-prefix

Here is my mpirun -info output

 `HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 4.1 Update 1
    Release Date:                            20130522
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Bootstrap servers available:             ssh rsh fork slurm srun ll llspawn.stdio lsf blaunch sge qrsh persist jmi
    Resource management kernels available:   slurm srun ll llspawn.stdio lsf blaunch sge qrsh pbs
    Checkpointing libraries available:        blcr
    Demux engines available:                  poll select`

My command line is:

`mpirun -ckpointlib blcr -ckpoint-prefix /home/user/temp/ckpoint -ckpoint-interval 1800 -np 274 $PROGPATH/myapp`

The way I send signal is `kill -s USR1 1900`, 1900 is the pid of miprun. Whenever I send the signal, the program simply ends. No crash though. Anybody has experience on MPI checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I send USR1 to mpirun, but I should send it to mpiexec.hydra instead. Even though some online article says mpirun and mpiexec are the same thing.